# Convert Yaml to excel in Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, yaml

I don't know how to parse efficiently a yaml file to transform it into an excel file...

I tried something like this but i think i could be much faster to rebuild the original excel look of the model :

```
for i,planche in enumerate (my_data["Culture par planche"]):
#print(planche)
for _planche in planche:
    print(planche[_planche][0]["surface"][0]["2"][0])
```

My yaml file content :

```
- Culture par planche :
- Planche A:
    - surface:
        - "2":
            - 198
    - Zones:
        - "1":
            - Rangs:
                - "1":
                    - surface:
                        - "2":
                            - 33
                    - plantes:
                        - Aubergine:
                            - nombre: 21
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 15
                            - poids total: 42
                            - Plantation:
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                            - Récolte:
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                                - 1
                        - Betteraves:
                            - nombre: 660
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 15
                            - poids total: 42
                            - Plantation:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                            - Récolte:
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                        - Epinards:
                            - nombre: 33
                            - surface totale nécessaire :3
                            - poids total :5
                            - Plantation:
                                - 10
                            - Récolte:
                                - 1
                                - 10
                                - 11
                                - 12
                        - Pois:
                            - nombre: 13
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 3
                            - poids total: 4.5
                            - Plantation:
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                            - Récolte:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                        - Blettes-poirées:
                            - nombre: 60
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 15
                            - poids total: 120
                            - Plantation:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                            - Récolte:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                        - Navet:
                            - nombre: 900
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 15
                            - poids total :30
                            - Plantation:
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                        - Fèves:
                            - nombre: 300
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 15
                            - poids total: 11.25
                            - Plantation:
                                - 10
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 4
                                - 5
                - "2":
                    - surface:
                        - "2":
                            - 33
                    - plantes:
                        - Fraise:
                            - nombre: 132
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 33
                            - poids total: 105
                            - Plantation:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                        - Ail:
                            - nombre: 200
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 10
                            - poids total: 20
                            - Plantation:
                                - 10
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 5
                                - 6
                - "3":
                    - surface:
                        - "2":
                            - 33
                    - plantes:
                        - Piments:
                            - nombre: 40
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 10
                            - poids total: 6
                            - Plantation:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                            - Récolte:
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                        - Poivrons:
                            - nombre: 30
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 10
                            - poids total: 50
                            - Plantation:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                            - Récolte:
                                - 6
                                - 10
                        - Haricots fil et rame:
                            - nombre: 25
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 10
                            - poids total: 17
                            - Plantation:
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                            - Récolte:
                                - 6
                                - 9
                        - Mesclun:
                            - nombre: 75
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 3
                            - poids total: 3
                            - Plantation:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                            - Récolte:
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                        - Navet:
                            - nombre: 1200
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 20
                            - poids total: 40
                            - Plantation:
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 11
                                - 12
                        - Radis:
                            - nombre: 7785
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 13
                            - poids total: 39
                            - Plantation:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 11
                                - 12
                - "4":
                    - surface:
                        - "2":
                            - 33
                    - plantes:
                        - Tomates:
                            - nombre: 100
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 20
                            - poids total: 220
                            - Plantation:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                            - Récolte:
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                                - 11
                        - Carottes:
                            - nombre: 910
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 13
                            - poids total: 39
                            - Plantation:
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                            - Récolte:
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                                - 11
                                - 12
                        - Oignons:
                            - nombre: 440
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 20
                            - poids total: 60
                            - Plantation:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                - "5":
                    - surface:
                        - "2":
                            - 33
                    - plantes:
                        - Tomates cerises:
                            - nombre: 100
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 20
                            - poids total: 240
                            - Plantation:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                            - Récolte:
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                        - Concombre:
                            - nombre: 13
                            - plans: 13
                            - INFO - 1 plante == 1 plan produit N concombres
                            - VOIR - rendement d'un plan de concombre
                            - poids total: 195
                            - Plantation:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                            - Récolte:
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                        - Roquette:
                            - nombre: 390
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 13
                            - poids total: 13
                            - Plantation:
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                            - Récolte:
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 10
                                - 11
                        - Pois: null
                        - nombre: 85
                        - surface totale nécessaire: 20
                        - poids total: 30
                        - Plantation:
                            - 9
                            - 10
                        - Récolte:
                            - 10
                            - 11
                            - 12
                - "6":
                    - surface:
                        - "2":
                            - 33
                    - plantes:
                        - Fraise:
                            - nombre: 132
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 33
                            - poids total: 105
                            - Plantation:
                                - 1
                                - 2
                                - 3
                                - 4
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 5
                                - 6
                                - 7
                                - 8
                                - 9
                                - 10
                        - Ail:
                            - nombre: 200
                            - surface totale nécessaire: 10
                            - poids total: 20
                            - Plantation:
                                - 10
                                - 11
                                - 12
                            - Récolte:
                                - 5
                                - 6
```

It's kinda huge but so you have the entire structure of a "planche", the entire yaml file contains 4 "planches"

this is how the excel model looks like basically :

[image]

If anyone has a clue to fill datas fast it would be welcome ! :)
PS : In "Plantation" and "Recolte" the integers represents months of the year

Answer (score 0):

Depending on python version you are using, you can try this:

First, install dependencies:

```
pip install xmltodict
pip install pyyaml
```

then...

```
import xmltodict
from yaml import SafeLoader

yaml_file=open("<your_yaml>","r")
python_dict=yaml.load(yaml_file,Loader=SafeLoader)
file=open("<future_xml_file>","w")
xml_string=xmltodict.unparse(python_dict,output=file)
file.close()
yaml_file.close()
```

Comment: Because it seems our main library from python to work with YAML files is not update: https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/#history